# Docker linking container

Tags: hyperlink, containers, docker

I read the Docker guide and I've a question about this page : https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/

Near the end, it's written :

> In addition to the environment variables Docker adds a host entry for the linked parent to the /etc/hosts file. Let's look at this file on the web container now.

```
root@aed84ee21bde:/opt/webapp
cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.7  aed84ee21bde
. . .
172.17.0.5  db
```

What's the command line I should execute to have a look in the web container?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before, they did: `docker run --rm --name web2 --link db:db training/webapp env`. In order to have the shell prompt, simply run bash in interactive mode: `docker run --rm -it --name web2 --link db:db training/webapp bash` then you can `cat /etc/hosts`

Alternatively, you can directly do `docker run --rm --name web2 --link db:db training/webapp cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. Is it fair to say this is not looking in the web container, but starting a new container to look in the image?

Comment: Yes and no. It will spawn a new container from the image so it will not look the actual running web container, and it will look at the image in read only. Any change you do will apply only to the new container.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @creack response on how to look at the hosts file using a shell from inside a container, you can also access the file from the host machine.

```
sudo cat `docker inspect --format '{{.HostsPath}}' web2`
```

The above one liner inspects the container named `web2` and uses a template (specified with `--format`) to return the path to the `hosts` file that is given to the container. Then it just uses `cat` to display it (it also uses `sudo`, to get the right access level since docker assigns the file to `root`)

An interesting side effect of this is that you can update the hosts file of a container (if you get root access to the host).